# Powershell set default sorting on datagrid

Tags: wpf, powershell, datagrid

So i have this wpf datagrid whose columns are defined in a xaml file,
i programmatically check data and insert rows in it 1 by 1 after a button is pressed.

I'm trying to understand how i can populate it and set a sorting (the same sorting as i would have clicking on a column header)

in winforms i used to add:

```
$myDataGrid.Sort($myDataGrid.Columns[3],'Ascending')
```

after my populating function.

How do i replicate that in WFP (and powershell)?

i did try:

```
$Datagrid.Items.SortDescription.Add([pscustomobject]@{ColumnName="MyColumn";SortDirection="ListSortDirection.Ascending"})
```

but i'm having quite some trouble as i only find c# explanations and trying to adapt is not working out....

Comment: It's `PropertyName` and `Direction`, not `ColumnName` and `SortDirection`: `$Datagrid.Items.SortDescription.Add([System.ComponentModel.SortDescription]@{PropertyName="MyColumn"; Direction="Ascending"})`

Comment: Throws an error: Exception during call of "Add" with 1 argument: the collection has fixed size

Comment: There's an `s` missing (it's `SortDescriptions`, not `SortDescription`)

Comment: It works! damn typos.
Where would you find the names anyway? i am having issues scraping microsoft documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$sortDescription = New-Object System.ComponentModel.SortDescription('MyColumn', 'Ascending')
$Datagrid.Items.SortDescriptions.Add($sortDescription)
```

Comment: Thank you! i like Mathias answer cause it's a one liner but you actually cleared a doubt i had about how to handle objects and creating them.

Answer (score 0):

In C# the solution is this, I hope this can help you to understand how WPF works.

To sort your DataGrid like if you clicked on your column 3, you have to **work on DataView created from WPF**. In this exampe the DataGrid is sorted every time that columns are AutoGenerated but you can select other event like DataGrid1_Loaded

```
using System.Windows.Data;

private void DataGrid1_AutoGeneratedColumns(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        (((DataGrid)sender).ItemsSource as DataView).Sort = DataGrid1.Columns[3].Header.ToString();
    }
```